# How does \tl_if_in:NnT work exactly?

Tags: expl3, latex3

I am trying to implement the insertion of Turkish epenthesis. If the input starts with one of `in, ın, un, ün` it's prepended with `n`. If not, then we look at the first letter. This time we prepend `y` if the first letter is one of `i, ı, u, ü, a, e, l`.

I am trying to understand how `\tl_if_in:NnT` works. I want to check if a string is in a list of strings.

Here is the code I tried but it does not work.

the list

```
\tl_set:Nx \l_genitive_sole_tl {{in} {ın} {un} {ün}}
```

the needle: it's supposed to be the first two letters of the parameter `#1`

```
\tl_set:Nx  \l_first_tl {\tl_range:Nnn {#1} {1} {2}}
```

test

```
\tl_if_in:NnTF \l_genitive_sole_tl  \l_first_two_tl
{
 code if TRUE
}
```

**EDIT**: added an example document. Sorry for not doing it on first post.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nx \l_genitive_sole_tl {{in} {ın} {un} {ün}}
\tl_set:Nx \l_vowel_init_tl {{i} {ı} {u} {ü} {a} {e} {l}}
\tl_new:N \l_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l_suffix_tl
\tl_new:N \l_first_two_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\addEP}{m}{
    \tl_set:Nx \l_suffix_tl {-{#1}}
    \tl_set:Nx  \l_first_tl {\tl_range:Nnn {#1} {1} {1}}    
    \tl_set:Nx  \l_first_two_tl {\tl_range:Nnn {#1} {1} {2}}
    \tl_if_in:NnTF \l_genitive_sole_tl \l_first_two_tl
    {
        \tl_set:Nx \l_suffix_tl {-n{#1}}
    }{
        \tl_if_in:NnT \l_vowel_init_tl  \l_first_tl
        {
            \tl_set:Nx \l_suffix_tl {-y{#1}}
        }
    }
    new suffix:
    \l_suffix_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
\addEP{in} % expect -nin here

\\
\addEP{ı} % expect -yı here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a more complete example?

Comment: thanks for adding more example, as I commnte din my answer you should not brace N arguments so `\tl_range:Nnn {#1}` is wrong (even if it might work in some cases)

Comment: I suspect that you should be using `seq_if_in`  not  `tl_if_in` as (as far as I can tell) you want to know if on of those specific items occurs, not just if some characters are a substring of the token list.

Comment: `\tl_range:Nnn` expects a tl variable in the first slot you are giving it `{in}` you should be using `:nnn` version not `:Nnn`

Comment: Tried :nnn. No luck.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it's also better to add a complete specification (not with TeX code). I see that `\addEP{n}` should produce `-nin`; but should `\addEP{ı}` produce `-yı` or `yi`? And what about other cases?

Comment: yes but you haven't really said what you want  it to do, so I'm just commenting on parts taht are clearly syntactically wrong, before considering th overall algorithim being implemented. As I said in my answr `\tl_if_in:NnTF \l_genitive_sole_tl \l_first_two_tl` is chacking if the tok `\l_first_two_tl` is in the  list which I am sure isn't what you want to test for.

Comment: `\addEP{ı} % expect -yi here` do you expct `-yi` ? My answer gives `-yı` which is what I thought you code was trying to produce. Can you clarify?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes you are right. It must just add "-y" if the input starts with "ı" but not with "ın" which is handled by the first conditional. Sorry for the typo in the edited post. I am correcting it now.

Comment: Question downvoted because it cannot be answered if you don't explain ***what*** you want to achieve. I can guess it has to do with the Turkish language, but I don't think there are many people here who know it; I don't.

Comment: Upon @egreg's suggestion: What I am trying to do is implement is the insertion of Turkish epenthesis. If the input starts with one of `in, ın, un, ün` it's prepended with `n`. If not, then we look at the first letter. This time we prepend `y` if the first letter is one of `i, ı, u, ü, a, e, l`. Thank you for suggesting ways to frame my questions properly.

Comment: @ErcanSolak Please, edit in your question.

Comment: Note that if you phrase it that way you could implement it without extracting the first and second character which is tricky in pdflatex. (But you havent said if pdftex is a requirement). In general when asking a question you should explain in words, don't assume that if you post dozens of lines on non working code that people can guess what it is intended to do. We can spot syntax errors and bad usage (such as repeated mis-use of N arguments) but the first version was impossible to guess the intent of the code and the second version still took a lot of guesswork)

Comment: Also please clarify what question you want to ask. In my answer I answered the question that you asked in comments about prefixes. It does not use `\tl_if_in:NnT` at all and so certainly does not answer the question in the title about how `\tl_if_in:NnT` works.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your answer that uses sequences works. Thank you for that. In my original question I had thought the problem was something to do how I was using `\tl_if_in:NnT`. Your solution uses sequences and `\seq_if_in`, which is all fine. Should I understand that the same cannot be done using token lists?

Comment: @ErcanSolak it could be done by token lists but not really what you want as a tl is just like a single string so even if you structure it as `{in}{un}{on}` then asking if `i` is in the list will be true as the structure is ignored, whereas if you make a sequence `in,un,on` and ask if `i` is a member of the sequence then that would be false. But actually you were not asking if `i` was a member of the list you were asking if the token `\l_first_tl` is in the list which is clearly false in any case (whatever definition `\l_first_tl` had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a `seq` here not a `tl` as you have a sequence of items to test.

[image]

The above is the output with lualatex or xelatex. With pdflatex you do not get that result without more work as taking the first token as here just gives you the first byte of a multi-byte UTF-8 character, not the whole first character.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% here you want a sequence and there is no expansion possible, so do not need x
\seq_const_from_clist:Nn \l_genitive_sole_seq {in, ın, un, ın}
\seq_const_from_clist:Nn \l_vowel_init_seq {i, ı, u, ı, a, e, l}
% The above both have repeated entries, is that intended?

\tl_new:N \l_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l_suffix_tl
\tl_new:N \l_first_two_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\addEP}{m}{
% I (think) you want no expansion and no {} around #1
    \tl_set:Nn \l_suffix_tl {-#1}
% Never use a brace group with an N argument
% Note this takes the first 1 or 2 tokens, so in pdftex this is the first
% byes of a multi-bye utf-8 character, not the first one or two characters.
    \tl_set:Nx  \l_first_tl {\tl_range:nnn {#1} {1} {1}}    
    \tl_set:Nx  \l_first_two_tl {\tl_range:nnn {#1} {1} {2}}

% V here as you want to test if the Value of \l_first_two_tl is in
    \seq_if_in:NVTF \l_genitive_sole_seq \l_first_two_tl
    {
% You do not want braces around #1, and no expansion so n not x
        \tl_set:Nn \l_suffix_tl {-n#1}
    }{
% V again
        \seq_if_in:NVT \l_vowel_init_seq  \l_first_tl
        {
% You do not want braces around #1, and no expansion so n not x
            \tl_set:Nn \l_suffix_tl {-y#1}
        }
    }
%    new suffix:
    \l_suffix_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\addEP{in} % expect -nin here


\addEP{ı} % expect -yi here

\end{document}
```

---

**Original Answer before updated question**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nx \l_genitive_sole_tl {{in} {ın} {un} {ın}}



\tl_set:Nx  \l_first_tl {\tl_range:Nnn {#1} {1} {2}}



\tl_if_in:NnTF \l_genitive_sole_tl  \l_first_two_tl
{
 code ~if ~TRUE
}

{
 code ~if ~False
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Produces Code if False

as  the content of `\l_genitive_sole_tl`  does not include the token `\l_first_two_tl`

things are perhaps clearer if you take note to always brace `n` arguments and never brace `N` argumens, so that last test would be

`\tl_if_in:NnTF \l_genitive_sole_tl  {\l_first_two_tl}`

I did wonder if you intended

```
\exp_args:NNV\tl_if_in:NnTF \l_genitive_sole_tl  \l_first_two_tl
```

to test the value of `l_first_two_tl`  but that isn't defined anywhere.

```
\exp_args:NNV\tl_if_in:NnTF \l_genitive_sole_tl  \l_first_tl
```

is woul be a valid test as that is defined except that `l_first_tl` has definition

```
\l_first_tl=macro:
->##1
```

and you are explicitly not allowed to test for `#` with `tl_if_in`.

---

The following code shows two working tests, returning TRUE for `in` and False for `on`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nx \l_genitive_sole_tl {in ın un ın}



\tl_if_in:NnTF \l_genitive_sole_tl {in}
{
 code ~if ~TRUE
}
{
 code ~if ~False
}

\par

\tl_if_in:NnTF \l_genitive_sole_tl {on}
{
 code ~if ~TRUE
}
{
 code ~if ~False
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: But the searched string must come from the first two letters of the parameter. Not defined explicitly.

Comment: @ErcanSolak That's just a question of doing an appropriate expansion to extract them

Comment: @ErcanSolak I answered the bits of your question that I could understand but I had to guess a lot of context. I see you have edit the question since. I'll re-read and may update this if no one else answers.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you please comment on how to handle the Unicode characters? As you commented in your answer, the `\tl_range`works byte-wise and cannot handle Unicode `ü` and `ı`. I am using PDFLaTeX.